# font weights differing in webkit and firefox

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, typography

Im finalizing a design for which ive been working soley in firefox up to this point, just taking it across to webkit the first time ive notice is my headings differ quite allot, they are in Helvetica Neue UltraLight 50px, so in css :

```
font-family: "helvetica neue"; font-weight:100; font-size:50px;
```

when viewed in firefox it looks like the version on the left

viewed in webkit (safari, chrome, ios safari) it looks like the version on the right

[image: firefox helvetica neue ultra light] [image: webkit helvetica neue ultra light]

any idea how i can bring these two further closer together ?

ive also made a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24CFE/) if any one wants to play around with the css,

Comment: Where is the `@font-face` declaration in the jsFiddle?

Comment: im not using one, its done using system fonts, and fall back alternatives

Comment: Ah! That's the issue then. Use `@font-face` so that it might fix! :)

Comment: is there no way to run this withough @font-face ? Due to the complication of having to license helvetica for use

Comment: Webkit browsers have crap font rendering, short of something like cufon there isn't a ton you can do about it. This is why I always do font choices in Chrome first because I know that's where they'll look the worst. Personally I'd live with it before using Cufon but to each their own on that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had luck with this in the past for pesky webkit fonts displaying bolder than intended:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

I would also recommend using a CSS @font-face to display Helvetica Neue fonts. Helvetica Neue is not on all computers and operating systems by default. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks parker, its and interesting approach but in this instance all it did was remove the antialiasing

Comment: Like Rick Calder said above, webkit has crap font rendering. I would definitely look into @font-face with Helvetica Neue - Have you browsed Google Fonts to look for a similar alternative?

Comment: Raleway might be a nice alternative: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Raleway

Answer (score 2):

From the images, it looks obvious that Firefox is using a thicker typeface of the family. I can’t guess why, and I cannot test on my computer – like most computers on the globe, it has no Helvetica Neue font.

And font availability is probably the most important issue here. What your `font-family` list causes on (almost all) Windows computers is that Arial will be used. And this means that the normal-weight (regular) typeface is used, since Arial has no thinner typeface.

So the best approach is probably to look for a free downloadable font and use it via `@font-face`. However, most of such fonts come with just two weights, or maybe even one, so you would need to focus on the relatively few fonts with, say, at least 6 typefaces, if you want something that exists both as 300 and as 100 weight. Perhaps [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) could be of sufficiently similar design – or at least acceptable design.

Answer (score 2):

try: -webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px

read more here:
http://css-tricks.com/beefing-up-dull-text-in-webkit/

Comment: Please provide more details with answer. This is almost like a link only answer. (The question was too old)

Answer (score 0):

**Add This Near the Top of Your Stylesheet**

```
/**
 * Fix fonts that render as bold in Firefox
 *
 * Put this near the top of your style.css
 * Before any overriding styles
 */

html {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/**
 * Firefox specific rule
 */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  body {
    font-weight: lighter !important;
  }
}
```

The `-moz` prefixed rules target only Firefox. The `-webkit` prefixed rules target Chrome and Safari, which use the Webkit rendering engine for their browser.

**Note:** If you also use `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` in your stylesheet, that can cause Internet Explorer to render some thicker fonts as bold when they should render as normal weight.

Reference from [website](https://www.lockedownseo.com/firefox-font-weight-too-bold/).