# google web-fonts weights in firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, google-webfonts

I am using roboto fonts in my project and have integrated the font as below in my HTML:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and in CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is: when i am using `font-weight` property , it is working correctly in Chrome but not in the Firefox, How can I make it work in Firefox??
[font weight 300, left one chrome right one firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iv1a.jpg)

Comment: Please check other questions in the Related section on the right. Possible duplicate of [font weights differing in webkit and firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144061/font-weights-differing-in-webkit-and-firefox?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with antialiasing on OSX, and FF allows you to control it via css just for OSX to fix it.

Add this to your CSS file.

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have restarted my ff browser from troubleshoot, Now it's working fine
thanks everybody. :)