# Font weight in Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 are different

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm working on Angular2 website and I have a issue with font weight(300) on bootstrap 3.3.7 and bootstrap 4 alpha. It render in different thickness (check only in Chrome). Anyone has noticed this or is this only a issue with my SASS.Much appreciate your help. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: well, there are many differences between bootstrap 3 and 4... And the `alpha` keyword says a lot. However it looks like standard webkit fonts problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144061/font-weights-differing-in-webkit-and-firefox

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, I checked the site in firefox too, but it would be the same. Any idea what is the special feature on bootstrap 4 alpha to make the font so thin at, font-weight:300?